# javascript or jQuery function for interaction between input fields value

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a html form where people can enter number of purchase item. Default value of that text field is 1.

```
<input type="text" size="5" value="1" id="position" class="amntstyle" name="position">
```

I want another text input field for price where the value would be 15 times of position automatically.

For example if someone enter 3 in position field, the price input field will get value 45 automatically. Like this

```
<input type="text" size="5" value="45" id="price" class="amntstyle" name="price">
```

Is it possible?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

simple .. use `javascript` functions and `onkeyup`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updatePrice(amount, element){
       var amount = parseInt(amount);
       if(!amount) amount = 0;
       var toUpdate = amount*15;
       document.getElementById(element).value = toUpdate;
    }
</script>


<input type="text" size="5" value="1" id="position"  class="amntstyle" name="position"  onkeyup="updatePrice(this.value,'price');">
<input type="text" size="5" value="45" id="price" class="amntstyle" name="price">
```

Answer (score 0):

**Working demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/YgheP/

Made it for specific scenario but you can tweak it to your needs.

Hope it feeds your cause. `:)`

also look for `isNaN` check and float value as well! `parseFloat(string)`

**code**

```
$('#position').keyup(function() {
    var price = parseInt(this.value) * 15;

    $('#price').prop('value', price);
});​
```

Comment: Gives an error in my firebug console.

$("#price").prop is not a function

but it works in jsfiddle.

Comment: Sorry, My jQuery version was old!
It is working like a charm now! Thanks a lot

Comment: @KhaledBinAQuadir All good bro! `:)` Glad it helped! yeah in older verson you can use api `.attr` instead of `.prop` but I reckon it worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to attach a eventhandler that will solve your problem:

```
$("#position").bind("change", function(){
   $("#price").val(parseInt($("#position").val()) * 15);
});
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is the YUI3 version:

```
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.6.0/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
<script>
    YUI().use("node", function(Y) {
        var priceNode = Y.one("#price");
        var positionNode = Y.one("#position");
        positionNode.on("change", function(e) {
             priceNode.set("value", positionNode.get("value")*15);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jquery then by using plugin formInteract, you just need to do this.

```
<input type="text" size="5" value="1" id="position" class="amntstyle" name="position"> 

<input type="text" size="5" value="45" id="price" class="amntstyle" name="price" data-bind-change-value="#position*15">
```

at bottom of the page just include this plugin file, everything else will be done itself.

here is the link to project
https://bitbucket.org/ranjeet1985/forminteract

You can use this plugin for many purpose like getting value of form, putting value to form, validation of form and many more. you can see some example of code in index.html file of project